# VSCode: Ctrl+F5 nor "Run Python file" work, but "python myfile.py" in built-in terminal does work

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, pressing Ctrl+F5, but also clicking "Run Python file" does not run the current file. Apart from this, using the built-in terminal with `python myfile.py` **does** work. The built-in terminal does have this warning sign with [the following message when hovering over it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tceEW.png)

Comment: Your description is too simple. Have you installed the necessary extensions like [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) according to this [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)?                        Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks JialeDu! I figured out what caused it and forgot to edit here.. The cause was that I had not set the workspace to the respective folder in the Explorer tab (on the left, at the top -- underneath the VSCode logo). Will add answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: set the workspace to the current folder in the `Explorer` tab (on the left, at the top -- underneath the VSCode logo).

Answer (score 0):

You may have configured specific startup parameters for **PowerShell**. Modify the default terminal to **CMD** with the following setting:

```
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
```

You can find out the parameters set for the poweshell terminal and modify or delete it, which may be related to the following setting:

```
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell",
            "args": []
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "Git Bash": {
            "source": "Git Bash"
        },
    },
```

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles*